# When should changes be committed in TDD when using GIT for source control?

Tags: git, tdd, scrum

We are discussing on how to structure our development workflow with TDD within SAFE for SCRUM . Although things are well structured, it is unclear to me when should one commit changes locally, and when to push them.

Should this be done everyday/ can there be mini-commits locally made within that duration, and should they be pushed upwards? what is the standard practice?

What does the framework dictates about the "when" and the "how often"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using develop & feature branches within GIT.

Your master branch should always contain a working deployable version of the software. All 'development' can be done on a develop branch and only merged into master when ready to release.

- Developers create their own feature branch and should check into this as often as they like (regularly)
- When each feature is complete, merge the feature branch into Develop
- When you have enough features, merge into Master for a release

The use of TDD should not affect your check-in strategy. The overall aim is to always have a working build.

Answer (score 1):

I am for develop and feature branches as already described. SAFE requires that granularity of commits is daily. That implies server side branches. It is also required that these commits have "working code" . Under TDD this means that test are passed.

So the policy is:

(1) A development branch where merges happen at least before the end of the sprint ( 3w AFAIK )

(2) Feature branches where implicated devs commit on *working code* at the end of the day

(3) Every commit must be *working code*

(4) Locally everyone can keep his own history, e.g. different branches with *non-working-code* , but should such push commits upwards.

Points (1) and (2) are actually open in SAFE, but (3) and (4) are not.

Keep in mind that TDD dictates that tests should be written before code development, but this is not always possibly, and under scrum they could be reiterated, but always before code evolution.

Comment: that's also a very nice answer, thanks!